# React Native only for UI components

Tags: ios, swift, reactjs, react-native, native

I have a very simple ViewController written in Swift with its UI built in Storyboard. It simply changes the text of a label when someone presses a button.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func changeText() {
        switch label.text! {
            case "Old Text":
                label.text = "New Text"
            case "New Text":
                label.text = "Old Text"
            default:
                break
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use React Native for my project but only to handle the UI components, not the app logic itself. How would I go about this? I have laid out the button and the text with react.

```
var Button = require('react-native-button');

class TestProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button style={styles.button}>Change Text</Button>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          Text to be changed
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  button: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'blue'
  },
});
```

More broadly speaking, if what I want is possible, is it still feasible to use this approach for more powerful and robust applications?

Answer (score 0):

Check this links they helped me a lot and I was in a similar situation.

https://teabreak.e-spres-oh.com/swift-in-react-native-the-ultimate-guide-part-1-modules-9bb8d054db03

https://github.com/JoelMarcey/swift-2048/blob/react-native/ios/swift-2048/ViewController.swift

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I totally agree with you but I'm not experience enough to provide a solution so this was the best help I could provide.